# SQL Select from many-to-many + phonegap

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cordova

I have a table called "lists", a table "products" and a table "lists_has_products".

My Table **lists**:

> - id
> - name
> - imgsrc

My Table **products**:

> - id
> - name
> - imgsrc
> - categoryid

My Table **lists_has_products**:

> - listid
> - productid

I want to select all products where the listid is equal to ... .
How can I do this? I already tried this with no result: (I'm working with phonegap)

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS p, LISTS_HAS_PRODUCTS l WHERE p.id = l.productid AND listid = " + listid, [], onSelectSupermarketsSuccess, onTxError);
```

He always goes straight to the 'onTxError' function. This is how I populate the lists_has_products table:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LISTS_HAS_PRODUCTS (listid, productid) VALUES (1, 2)');
```

Comment: I`m not sure about a number as an alias,change it to something else.

Comment: I think it is a lower case L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a JOIN syntax?

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT P.* FROM PRODUCTS P INNER JOIN LISTS_HAS_PRODUCTS L ON P.id = L.productid WHERE listid " + listid, [], onSelectSupermarketsSuccess, onTxError);
```